# How to fix object auto reorder min to max in for (in) loop

Tags: javascript, for-loop, for-in-loop

My final function.

```
var timeToString = function(time)
{
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        return '0';
    }
    else
    {
        var s = '';
        var d;

        var dateObj = { '_86400' : 'วัน', '_3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '_60' : 'นาที', '_1' : 'วินาที' };

        for ( key in dateObj )
        {
            console.log( time + ' ' + key )

            var suffix = dateObj[key];
            var totaltime = key;
            totaltime = totaltime.substr(1)

            if ( time >= totaltime )
            {
                time -= d = time - time % totaltime;
                s += ( ( d / totaltime) + ' ' + suffix + ' ');
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}

document.write( timeToString(79) )
```

Result: `1 นาที 19 วินาที`

It's work well about my fix by adding prefix to key value of my object to fix it.

this is my first code

```
var timeToString = function(time)
{
    if (time <= 0)
    {
        return '0';
    }
    else
    {
        var s = '';
        var d;

        var dateObj = { '86400' : 'วัน', '3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '60' : 'นาที', '1' : 'วินาที' };

        for ( key in dateObj )
        {
            var suffix = dateObj[key];
            var totaltime = parseInt(key);

            if ( time >= totaltime )
            {
                time -= d = time - time % totaltime;
                s += ( ( d / totaltime) + ' ' + suffix + ' ');
            }
        }
    }
    return s;
}
```

Result: `79 วินาที`

I don't need display like that.

Result: `1 นาที 19 วินาที`

It's correct.

look difference about "dateObj" between two function.

How to fix object reorder in for in loop if type of key == number

Comment: wow, i couldn't understand anything of this question....

Comment: var dateObj = { '_86400' : 'วัน', '_3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '_60' : 'นาที', '_1' : 'วินาที' };

when in for in loop it display '_86400' first but.

var dateObj = { '86400' : 'วัน', '3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '60' : 'นาที', '1' : 'วินาที' };

in for in loop it display '1' first

Answer (score 0):

As I understood you need to format minutes.
Try this example:

```
function formatTime(minutes) {
        var hh = Math.floor(minutes/60);
        var mm = minutes%60;
        var result = "";
        if (hh > 0)
            result += hh + " hours ";
        if (mm > 0)
            result += mm + " minutes";
        return result;
    }
```

Then call:

```
console.log(formatTime(219));
// 3 hours 39 minutes
```

Comment: I need to know why object key reorder in for in loop

Comment: var dateObj = { '_86400' : 'วัน', '_3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '_60' : 'นาที', '_1' : 'วินาที' };

when in for in loop it display '_86400' first but.

var dateObj = { '86400' : 'วัน', '3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '60' : 'นาที', '1' : 'วินาที' };

in for in loop it display '1' first

Comment: You shouldn't rely on ordering in for in loops. It can differ from browser to browser.

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me the problem is actually in the line

```
 totaltime = totaltime.substr(1)
```

that you change to

```
var totaltime = parseInt(key);
```

i don't know what you want to compare here, bet it seems to be 2 completely different comparison you do. make sure what do you want to compare and how to do it. what it `time` and who send it? how do you want to compare integer to string? and so on

Comment: I confuse about for in loop key index  display first

Comment: var dateObj = { '_86400' : 'วัน', '_3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '_60' : 'นาที', '_1' : 'วินาที' };
And
dateObj = { '86400' : 'วัน', '3600' : 'ชั่วโมง', '60' : 'นาที', '1' : 'วินาที' }; 

in for in loop

Comment: @MarosdeeUma i'm sorry but if you can't write in English i can't help you

Comment: var dateObj = { '_86400' : 'Day', '_3600' : 'Hours', '_60' : 'Minutes', '_1' : 'Seconds' }; And var dateObj = { '86400' : 'Day', '3600' : 'Hours', '60' : 'Minutes', '1' : 'Seconds' };
sorry about that